# Django: How to query from two models with a common foreign key to third model and a common non foreign key field?

Tags: django

I have two models, both of them have a foreign key to the `User` model and a common date field `schedule_date`. Here are the model definitions:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    schedule_date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='schedule_set')
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    breaks = JSONField()

class Attendance(models.Model):
    schedule_date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='attendance_set')
    calculated_attendance = models.DecimalField(null=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
    adjusted_attendance = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='attendance_approved_by_set', null=True)
    approved_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    calculation_details = JSONField()
```

I want to fetch the rows from `Attendance` model with some filter conditions and also want to access the corresponding `Schedule` row for each row where the `schedule_date` is the same. In terms on SQL, I want to run the following query:

```
select 
    a.user_id, 
    a.schedule_date, 
    a.calculated_attendance,
    a.calculation_details,
    s.start_time,
    s.end_time,
    s.breaks
from "Attendance" a, "Schedule" s
where a.user_id = s.user_id
and a.schedule_date = s.schedule_date
and <more filter conditions on Attendance table>
```

Comment: Although this can be done, I think the modeling is a bit strange. Shouldn't it make more sense to link an `Attendance` object to a `Schedule` then, since then if for example the `schedule_date` of a `Schedule` changes, then this would automatically reflect in the `Attendance` that is linked to it.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!